# Chapter footnotes (using symbols, not appearing in TOC or header)

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

I want to make a macro `sfootnote` specifically for footnotes on Chapter headings, such that the footnote marks are some constant symbol (e.g., '*'), and such that the marks/footnotes don't appear in the TOC. Also, I don't want these footnotes to affect the numbering of other footnotes.

Example intended use of `sfootnote` macro:

```
\chapter{Title\sfootnote{Info on chapter...}}\label{chap:reasoning}
```

(I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright]{report}
```

and `fancyhdr` for headers.)

Now, knowing that I'm not the first person to try this, I've had a bit of a Google, and I've had success putting non-floating footnotes in the headings using simply:

```
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\newcommand{\sfootnote}[1]{\footnote{#1}}
```

...but these have ugly (albeit static) numbers as footnote marks.

And I've had success using symbol marked footnotes in headings using:

```
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\sfootnote}[1]{\protect\symbolfootnote[1]{#1}}
```

...but these "float" into the TOC and headers (the mark and footnote in the TOC, only the mark in the header).

I've tried various combinations of these, but only managed to induce various sorts of errors (or no change at all).

I've been at this for about an hour and a half, with no luck (or, more accurately, no skill).

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try manyfoot along with the test footmisc uses to keep the footnotes out of the toc and the header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newfootnote{B}
\makeatletter
\def\sfootnote#1{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \Footnotemark{*}\FootnotetextB{*}{#1}%
  \else
    \relax
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\section{abc\sfootnote{cde}}

text\footnote{foot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Ulrike. Sorry to bump this, but I'm just coming around to using the `hyperref` package for some text using the above command(s). If I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` into your MWE above (after `manyfoot` is included), I get 31 errors. Any thoughts on making the above solution work with `hyperref`?

Comment: `\section[abc]{abc\sfootnote{cde}}`. Btw: the number of errors doesn't matter, one is already too much.